# What does this python condition statement do?

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm trying to do some image processing. I have a code that load the image by `cv2.imread()` into `image` variable and then convert it from `RGB` to `Gray` and set the result in `grayImage`. Now I cannot understand what this part of code is doing:

```
if grayImage[0,0] < 120:
    image = grayImage > (grayImage[0,0] + 30)
```

I can see the result but not understand what is happening?

Comment: That depends on what `grayImage` is (as in what is its type). Python allows operator overloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the if clause it checks if the pixel 0,0 is less than 120.

If this is true it creates an array with boolean values. It checks for every pixel if the value at that pixel is larget than the value from grayImage[0,0]+30 (so larger than the value at position 0,0 + 30). If so this pixel will be set to true, else it will be false. In the end you have a new array consisting of boolean values.

I assumed in this answer that you have numpy arrays. Otherwise please specify what datatype you have.

Comment: thank @Syrius. Yes it is a numpy array. But what happens to image when (`grayImage > (grayImage[0,0] + 30)`) is true or false? I mean at the end `image`(variable) is an image that i can see in a pyplot.

Comment: It is just a boolean array. So the image looks something like [[True,True,False],[False,True,False]]. I guess you can plot this as a black and white image. The grayImage however is not touched by this command

Comment: Oh yes! I print it and it is just true and false. thank a lot.